# Spring Boot OneToOne referencedColumnName not applied

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE user_profile (
    id VARCHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE user_phone (
    id VARCHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id VARCHAR(36),
    phone_number VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    code VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    validated_at DATETIME NULL
);

ALTER TABLE user_phone ADD CONSTRAINT user_phone_FK FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user_profile(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

so child has ID reference to his parent, because if I will delete parent I want this child to be deleted also.
In User class I have:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_profile")
public class UserProfile {
...
@OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
    private UserPhone phoneNumber;
```

but then when I run it I see in JPA logs:

> from
> user_profile userprofil0_
> where
> userprofil0_.id=?

why it looks there by ID ? should be by user_id field. Or I missunderstood smth there..

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One day later and finally I found the solution.
Its pretty tricky in spring and not maybe so intuitive.

So - from user_phone table Ive removed additional ID column, and now user_id is there primary key, only 1 change in sql.

Then in spring:

in UserProfile:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "userProfile", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private UserPhone userPhone;
```

and in UserPhone:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
@Type(type = "uuid-char")
private UUID id;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@MapsId
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private UserProfile userProfile;
```

@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation indicates that the primary key of the UserProfile is used as the foreign key value for the associated UserPhone.